# Why does some of my css selectors not working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am new to css/html and I am trying to copy a videos code. I did it line by line the same way but for some reason the code works out differently. First thing is the auto-fit in .container .row100. Second thing is the selectors with commas. I have been trying forever to figure out what I did wrong but I cant figure it out.

here is the code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

section{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #001923;
}

section::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(#ffeb3b, #e91e63);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-420px, -180px);
}

section::after{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background: linear-gradient(#2196f3, #83d8ff);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(400px, 180px);
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    padding:50px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 25px 45px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
}

.container::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -40%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: skewX(-15deg);
}

.container h2{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container .row100{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px,1fr))
}

.container .row100 .col{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 30px 0 20px;
}

.container .row100 .col .inputBox{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}

.container .row100 .col .inputBox input,
.container .row100 .col .inputBox textarea{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #000;
}

.container .row100 .col .inputBox .text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.5s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.container .row100 .col .inputBox input:focus + .text,
.container .row100 .col .inputBox input:valid + .text,
.container .row100 .col .inputBox textarea:focus + .text,
.container .row100 .col .inputBox textarea:valid + .text{
    top: -35px;
    left: -10px;
}

.container .row100 .col .inputBox .line{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border-radius: 2px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.container .row100 .col .inputBox input:focus ~ .line,
.container .row100 .col .inputBox input:valid ~ .line{
    height: 100%;
}

.container .row100 .col .inputBox.textarea{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.container .row100 .col .inputBox textarea:focus ~ .line,
.container .row100 .col .inputBox textarea:valid ~ .line{
    height: 100%;
}

.container .row100 .col input[type="submit"]{
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none; 
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Make Request Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\haloe\PycharmProjects\Reimbursements - Copy\styles\makeRequestPage.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Reimbursement Request Form</h2>
            
                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputbox">
                            <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                            <span class="text">First Name</span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputbox">
                            <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                            <span class="text">Last Name</span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputbox">
                            <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                            <span class="text">Email</span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputbox">
                            <input type="text" name="" required="required">
                            <span class="text">Mobil</span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="inputbox textarea">
                            <textarea required="required"></textarea>
                            <span class="text">Type message here</span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row100">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="button" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

here is the video for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdEzWQfgZgw

here is what it is supposed to look like:
[image: here is what it is supposed to look like]

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be in your html, since you have only one column per row. Using two columns per row should fix it.

Print from the code on the video :  [image]

Comment: That fixed the layout but everything else is still wrong